# Do multiple running instances of the same executable binary share the same RAM image?

Tags: ram, process, nodejs

If I have, say, two long-running Node applications (think Express), do the two instances of Node code share the same physical memory?

Data segments certainly will be separate, but do all code segments of the same binary load into separate RAM?

Comment: All the sharable libraries are shared. Unless code segments are marked "sharable" they're not.

Comment: I wouldn't care but if I did I would load one instance, check `free` output, load another instance, check `free` output again, etc.

Comment: Wouldn't paging make the numbers hard to decipher? (I asked because I am trying to determine the lowest cost to operate a number of hobbyist web sites.)